# How to add a user to Wheel group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to add a use to wheel group using in a Ubuntu server.

> sudo usermod -aG wheel john

I get:

> usermod: group 'wheel' does not exist

On my /etc/sudoers I have this:

```
>  cat /etc/sudoers
> # sudoers file.
> #
> # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
> #
> # See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
> #
> 
> # Host alias specification
> 
> # User alias specification
> 
> # Cmnd alias specification
> 
> # Defaults specification
> 
> # User privilege specification root    ALL=(ALL) ALL %root   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
> 
>     %wheel  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Do I have to do groupadd of wheel?

Comment: Does the group "wheel" exist? Try `grep wheel /etc/group`. Another thing, _why_ are you trying to add someone to the wheel group? Beware the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: grep wheel /etc/group doen't find anything

Comment: So, the wheel group does not exist. Again, what is it you are really trying to do?

Comment: i am just getting used to with ubuntu, i am new with unix roles and user

Comment: does  that mean i need to do groupadd wheel? my assumpution was wheel is a bulit in group

Comment: OK, please update your question explaining _why_ you need to add a user to the wheel group. This really sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). In general, yes, in order to add a user to a group, you need to create the group first.

Comment: ok, my assumptuion was wheel and admin are bulit in groups

Comment: Wheel is FreeBSD admin group

Comment: It is pretty clear what the need is, if sudoers in configured for the %wheel group, I need to add my user to that group, typically by adding the user id or name to the list on the 'wheel' entry in /etc/group

Comment: @terdon this is wheel group: https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/users_groups_linux8/#option-2-grant-elevated-privileges-to-a-user

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes, thank you, I am well aware of the `wheel` group, which is why I also know it isn't used on Ubuntu where you would add a user to the `sudo` group instead, hence my question to the OP to understand if the actual objective here was to have a user be able to run `sudo` or if they need the actual group `wheel` to be added to the system for some other reason.